# Downgrading Java 11 to java 8?

Tags: 18.04, java, downgrade

How can i downgrade the java version 11 to java 8. As i need jenkins, current jenkins versoin doesn't support java 11. I need to downgrade.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

1. You have to install the `openjdk-8-jre`:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
   ```
2. Next switch to the jre-8 version:

   ```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
    There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

    Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

    * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1500      auto mode
      1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1500      manual mode
      2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1500      manual mode
   ```
3. Add JAVA_HOME variable:

   ```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
   ```
4. check java version:

   ```
    $ java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
   ```

Same procedure for Oracle java.

Comment: What is `update-alternatives`? I get `sudo: update-alternatives: command not found` when I try to run it. I don't have apt installed. Is it part of that?

Comment: When I try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` I get this error: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local. 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).`How to remove oracle-java11-installer-local.

Comment: What about uninstalling the unused jdk 11?