# Minecraft 1.12 and under won't run

Tags: java, crash, minecraft

Minecraft 1.12.2 and below won't load on Ubuntu 18.4. 
It is crashing right after I launch it.
When it crashes it just says "An unexpected error occurred and the game has crashed. We're sorry for the inconvenience."
The logs end up like this

```
[20:18:38] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Notme2222
[20:18:39] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
```

The LWJGL version varies based on what version I'm trying to run, the one above is 1.12.2.
Any LWJGL version above 3.0.0 works, which is 1.13 and up.
I think the LWJGL is the problem but I don't know how to fix it.
I have downloaded the latest version (2.9.3 + dfsg-1) of liblwjgl-java, liblwjgl-java-doc, and liblwjgl-java-jni from synaptic package manager.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. My Minecraft server runs smooth and easy using OpenJDK 11, right out of the 19.10 Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: The issue persists on 19.10

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its crashing is because of java 11. you need to install java 8 and under and everything should be fine. here's a post on how to do it: [Downgrading Java 11 to java 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133216/downgrading-java-11-to-java-8).
and if that doesn't work go and try a youtube video on how to do it.

Comment: This answer works. Fixed everything.